# Database based solution for TDSP (Fastest)

Tags: pgrouting, shortest-path

I have tried `pgRouting` in `PostGres` for finding shortest path

```
select d.*, bs.starttime, bs.endtime, bs.trip_id from pgr_dijkstra(
    'select id, source, target, traveltime as cost from my_table',
    19,
    21,
    directed := true
) d JOIN my_table bs on d.edge = bs.id;
```

The above doesn't consider `time` as parameter. Before selecting the next `edge`, I want to check the time of the transport as well.

Eg:

```
A ---- > B (03.00PM) (travel time 5)

B ---- > C (3.30PM) (travel time 15)

B ---- > C (11:00AM) (travel time 10)
```

Current algorithm consider the path with travel time 10 (Without considering the time).

Is there a standard solution for this. I have seen lot of implementations like `A* algorithm`. I'm talking about `half million` edges.

Or is there any way to get a hook on previous node or next node while computing pgr algorithms ?

Comment: what's the resolution of your daily travel time values, 30mins.? ...seems rather brutish to have 48 columns (in a closely related second table, maybe) for travel time, but that could be a workaround (pass in time of interest to a wrapper function and base the routing cost on the respective/closest travel time column). any higher resolution would become a pain, though.

Answer (score 0):

Many years ago a function named `TDSP` (Time-dependent shortest path) was developed. It's probably what you are looking for, and the source code is still available in the Git repository tagged with `gsoc/tdsp-lw`: 
https://github.com/pgRouting/pgrouting/tree/gsoc/tdsp-lw

However, it was very experimental that time and has not been updated since then, so it is not available in current releases and I can't tell if it will still work. Someone had to port it and probably put quite some effort into making it work (again).

Comment: I had a look at it. Doesn't seem compatible with pgRouting 2.x and doesnt seem accurate. Do you have any alternative suggestions ?

Comment: No, at the moment I do not know about an alternative. Someone either had to make this work (again) or be able to fund the development.